# CFT to CDK migration - how to reference CFT created objects from CDK code

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I read [this description](https://garbe.io/blog/2019/09/11/hey-cdk-how-to-migrate/) on how to import a Cloud Formation Template (CFT) into your CDK code.

This is interesting but there doesn't appear to be a way to use any of the objects created by the CFT in the CDK code.  So if for example you have an apigateway or appsync instance defined in CFT and want to use the really nice mechanism for creating Lambda functions in CDK, there doesn't appear to be a way to attach the Lambda function to the apigateway or appsync instance.

This means it's a complete fork lift upgrade to move from CFT to CDK if there's no way to reference CFT objects from the CDK.  That doesn't sound right though, it would be a significant barrier to adoption.

How would one reference a CFT-created object in CDK code?   Here are four possible examples, a solution to any one of them should be able to answer the question by revealing the pattern of code to be used:

1. Lambda function created by CDK uses a DynamoDB table created in a CFT
2. Lambda function created by CDK attached to an API gateway that was created in a CFT
3. Lambda function created by CDK attached to an appsync resolver created in a CFT
4. Or any other example where a CFT object is used by CDK code.

I note the [documentation tells you how to get an an ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/use_cfn_template.html), but doesn't tell you what you can do with that ARN in CDK code.

Answer (score 1):

The [second part](https://garbe.io/blog/2019/09/20/hey-cdk-how-to-use-existing-resources/) of the blog series that [you referenced](https://garbe.io/blog/2019/09/11/hey-cdk-how-to-migrate/) gives two examples, one for VPC and one for ALB.

> **How can I reference existing resources?**
>
> Most of the time it’s necessary to reference existing resources which have already been created in your AWS account. Either by another CloudFormation Stack or by another CDK App.
>
> To do that, many of the CDK Constructs support fromXXX() methods.
>
> **Example VPC**
>
> ```
> const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'MyExistingVPC', { isDefault: true });
> ```
>
> **Example ALB**
>
> ```
> const existingAlb = elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer.fromApplicationLoadBalancerAttributes(this, "ImportedALB", {
>   loadBalancerArn: "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:123456789012...",
>   securityGroupId: "MyAlbSecurityGroupA12345AB"
> });
> ```

You can then use the existing resource references as objects in your CDK code. Here is an example using the VPC.

```
const fn = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
  handler: 'index.handler',
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'lambda-handler')),
  vpc: vpc
});
```

Comment: The `fromXXXX` method does not appear to work for the ApiGateway, which creates an iRestAPI not a RestApi
`// this fails because api is of type IRestAPI not RestApi api.root.addMethod("GET", getWidgetsIntegration); // GET /`

Comment: `api.root.addMethod("GET", getWidgetsIntegration);` will modify your RestAPI. The answer that I gave is relevant for referencing an external resource from within the CDK app. Look under the ApplicationLoadBalancer class for the fromApplicationLoadBalancerAttributes method. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2/applicationloadbalancer.html#aws_elasticloadbalancingv2_ApplicationLoadBalancer_fromApplicationLoadBalancerAttributes

Comment: I think that there are very few APIs that allow an import. LoadBalancer and VPC yes.   ApiGateway and AppSync, no.   Alas it is difficult to find a canonical list, as the search functionality of the docs is very limited.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.RestApi.html#static-from-wbr-rest-wbr-api-wbr-idscope-id-restapiid shows the ApiGateway fromRestApiId method. It returns IRestAPI which is an interface. It sounds to me like you're trying modify a resource from within CDK that was previously created outside CDK. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure of the difference between "modify" a resource and "add to the resource" since one adds `Methods` to API gateways, but I guess the answer is "yes".

Comment: I'm not sure what one can actually do with an `IRestAPI`.  Doesn't look like much. 
 Perhaps we should take this to gitter:  https://gitter.im/awslabs/aws-cdk.

Comment: it looks like DynamoDB supports this:  `fromTableArn` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-dynamodb.Table.html#static-from-wbr-table-wbr-arnscope-id-tablearn

Comment: I think my answer isn't exactly what you're looking for. Hopefully gitter provides some help. Your initial links in you post seem to be on the right track. I'm not as familiar with that functionality.

Comment: DynamoDB use case works, you have to convert the iResolvable ARN to a strong explicitly.  Will provide more complete answer in different answer

Answer (score 1):

Some APIs explicitly support referencing an existing or to-be-created instance.  Some do not.  So the asked-for use cases cannot be all supported.  Here's the status of the list and the support as it currently stands, followed by a full example for one that works.   Alas, the most simple stuff works and the most complex constructs such as ApiGateway and AppSync do not.  This means fork-lift upgrade.

Note:  AWS might fix this issue, [see for updates](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/issues/270)

1. Lambda function created by CDK uses a DynamoDB table created in a CFT - **Works**.   See example below.
2. Lambda function created by CDK attached to an API gateway that was created in a CFT - ApiGateway has a `fromXXX` function but doesn't resolve to a useful object.  [See](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.RestApi.html#static-from-wbr-rest-wbr-api-wbr-idscope-id-restapiid)
3. Lambda function created by CDK attached to an appsync resolver created in a CFT - AppSync is in Public beta and does not have a `fromXXX` function.  [See](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-appsync.GraphQLApi.html)

**Example DynamoDB instance in CFT, add a lambda function that uses the table**

```
const existingTemplate = new cdk.CfnInclude(this, "ExistingInfrastructure", {
  template: yamlParse(fs.readFileSync("aws-stack.yaml").toString())
});
const ddbArn = cdk.Fn.getAtt("DynamoDBUserTable", "Arn");   // DynamoDBUserTable is a named element in aws-stack.yaml of type DynamoDB::Table
const userTable = dynamodb.Table.fromTableArn(this, 'importedTable', ddbArn.toString());
const handler = new lambda.Function(this, "UserGetHandler", {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X, // So we can use async in user-get.js
  code: lambda.Code.asset("resources"),
  handler: "user-get.main",
});

userTable.grantReadWriteData(handler);
```